# Given an isosceles triangle inscribing a unit circle, what angle θ makes the area of the largest circular segment equal to the sum of the other two?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, circles, area

Please see diagram below.

I am trying to find an expression for $θ$ that makes the area of the bottom region $(2a)$ equal to the sum of the other two areas $(a)$.
Assume this is a unit circle, so $r=1$.

[image: Diagram not drawn to scale]
Diagram not drawn to scale

[image: Diagram #2]

The area of circular segment $a$ of a unit circle is: $A_a = \frac{θ_1 - sin(θ_1)}{2}$
Note that this $θ_1$ is not the $θ$ shown in the first diagram, but that: $θ_1 = π - θ$

The area of circular segment $2a$ of a unit circle is $A_{2a} = \frac{θ_2 - sin(θ_2)}{2}$

Let: $A_a = \frac{A_{2a}}{2}$
Then we have: $\frac{θ_1 - sin(θ_1)}{2} = \frac{θ_2 - sin(θ_2)}{4}$

We know that: $θ_1 + \frac{θ_2}{2} = π$
Solving for $θ_1$ we get: $θ_1 = π - \frac{θ_2}{2}$

After substituting we get:
$\frac{(π - \frac{θ_2}{2}) - sin(π - \frac{θ_2}{2})}{2} = \frac{θ_2 - sin(θ_2)}{4}$

If I could solve this for $θ_2$, finding $θ$ would be trivial.
The Inscribed Angle Theorem says that: $θ = \frac{θ_2}{2}$

I was able to get what looks like a numerical approximation using wolframalpha, but I can't find a closed form solution. I think $θ$ works out to be: $1.2473826912977909520$ radians or $71.46976364903345985$ degrees

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Give your thoughts on the problem, or context about where you found it.

Comment: Assume radius r and base a (they are related with $\theta$) - from there calculate the sectors - you get two equations with two unknowns.

Comment: A numerical solution is often the best you can get for this kind of equations where the same unknown appears both inside and outside a trig function. Having closed-form solutions for that is the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: It's easy to see that the answer is between $60^\circ$ (where the sum of the two "side" sectors is bigger than the "bottom" sector) and $90^\circ$ (where the sum of the two "side" sectors is smaller than the "bottom" sector) so at least you have a sanity check on your answer.

Comment: @Henry, your equation is not the same as the OP's equation.

Comment: @NickD in his defense his comment was posted before I added my equations.

Comment: Oh, I doubt he needs any defending :-) My comment was directed more to latecomers (like me) who might be puzzled by the discrepancy.

Comment: @NickD, Oh, I just looked at his profile. I'm new here. I wasn't aware of his celebrity :) more likely that MY equation is wrong lol.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you got it right.

Comment: If you are talking about me, I did not know I was a celebrity. In any case I can be wrong, and looking again at this particular case I probably am.  So I will delete my earlier comment. The answer in the question of  $1.24738269$ looks reasonable.  It is also a solution of $2\theta +\sin(\theta)(1-\cos(\theta))=\pi$